# Java methods name convention

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, androguard

Where can I find the documentation for the syntax of the method name convention used in Androguard?

After searching for a while, it seems it's the same as in Java when a error happens.

A code example:

```
from androguard import misc
import sys

a, d, dx = misc.AnalyzeAPK(sys.argv[1])

c = list(dx.get_classes())[0]
m = list(c.get_methods())[0]
print(m.method)
```

Here is an example method name:

```
Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V [access_flags=public constructor] @ 0x8619c
```

Comment: https://androguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this page about the [JNI types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html), which is what I was looking for.

The `L` means fully-qualified-class, while the `V` is void, the type of the method.